# Is potential difference the difference in electric potential energy or electric potential?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, voltage, definition

Referencing the book [*Physics for Scientist and Engineers*, Ninth Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133947271), the book says that "Potential Difference should not be confused with Difference in Potential Energy."

I also reviewed several internet sources that say "Potential Difference is the difference in Electric Potential Energy between two points."

What is the difference between potential difference and a difference in potential energy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Technically* "potential difference" is the difference in electrical potential, i.e. $\Delta V$, not the difference in electrical potential energy, $\Delta U$. Potential difference ($\Delta V$) is also called voltage, in certain contexts.

However, many people and sources are sloppy about their terminology, and they will say just "potential" when they really mean potential energy. An expert could tell which is meant based on context - or, in some cases, that it doesn't matter. Since potential energy is related to potential by $U = qV$, if the charge $q$ is known and constant, you can usually say the same things about either quantity $U$ or $V$.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the relationship is $\Delta U = q \Delta V$, so if the magnitude $q$ of the charge under discussion is constant and understood, then the distinction is a simple multiplicative factor.

Comment: Potential is an intensive quantity: a large 12V battery has the same potential as a small 12V battery.   Potential energy is an extensive quantity, and the big battery has more of it.

Comment: @dmckee sure, I guess that's worth a mention. I don't want to take the answer too far off point by including too much else though.